# Duplicate TreeView's undelying rows to create a copy of exising TreeView

Tags: c#, sql-server, treeview

hi to the best my real friends . thank you and my favorite StackOverFlow.com

i have a TreeView control to view some hierarchical data .
as you know there is a underlying DataTable (base on a sql server table) as DataSource to this TreeVeiw .

my problem is : how to duplicate one root and entire of it's leaves as a new branch of my TreeView .

duplicating a TreeView node is kind of simple i think (by using TreeNode Clone() method) .
but what about underlying DataTable ?
how to copy entire tree rows into the same table ? 
the ID column is identity but how to set ParentID column base on the recently inserted parent row in the table ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The most direct approach is to use a recursive method that iterates the cloned tree nodes.  Each node will locate and update its own record in the DataTable object.  Here's a basic WinForm code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Demo {
    public class TestClass {
        DataTable table;

        public void Initialize() {
            table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("ParentID", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("Text", typeof(String));
        }

        private void UpdateTreeData(TreeNode parentNode) {
            int parentId = Convert.ToInt32(parentNode.Tag);
            int childId;
            foreach (TreeNode n in parentNode.Nodes)
            {   // Assuming Tag contains the table ID value...
                childId = Convert.ToInt32(n.Tag);
                table.Select("ID = " + childId.ToString())[0]["ParentID"] = parentId;
                UpdateTreeData(n);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot Mike . your solution works great when primary key of table(ID) is not Identity or AutoNumber .in fact in this scenario we don't insert any value to ID column but it is filled after a record was inserted . 
is it any way to do this ? or i have to use non identity column instead Inevitably ?

Comment: You may insert an arbitrary value into the ID column. When the DataTable updates the database (I assume SQL Server), the database automatically disregards any value in the auto-increment identity, and injects its own value. Therefore, you want to synchronize your DataTable object with the actual database ID column values, before updating the tree nodes.  Otherwise, the values you inserted in the DataTable may not match those in the database.